# Alterar tamanho de uma imagem pelo java script (document.getElementById("showw").src="img/sua_imagem.jpg"

Tags: javascript

criei uma div com a id conteudo( e dentro da div criei um

ai através do javascript estou tentando inserir uma imagem da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#btn1").click(function(){
  document.getElementById('showw').src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tytPcvyJASc";
  $("#conteudo").show();
 })

 $("#btn2").click(function(){
  document.getElementById('showw').src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B92VAqP2dw";
  $("#conteudo").show();
 })

 $("#btn3").click(function(){
  document.getElementById('showw').src = "";
  $("#conteudo").show();
 })

 $("#btn4").click(function(){
  var img1 = document.getElementById('showw')
  img1.src = "img/fusca1.jpg";
  img1.style.width = 30;
  img1.style.height = 30;

  $("#conteudo").show();
 })

 $("#btn5").click(function(){
  var img2 = document.getElementById('showw')
  img2.style.width = 599;
  img2.style.height = 399;

  $("#conteudo").show();
 })

 $("#btn6").click(function(){
  var img3 = document.getElementById('showw').src = "img/fusca1.jpg";
  img3.style.width = 599+"px";
  img3.style.height = 399+"px";

  $("#conteudo").show();
 })
});
```

```css
#corpo{
 background: black;
}
#cpesquerdo{
 width: 400px;
 height: 220px;
 border: solid 2px #00FFFF;
 background: #8A2BE2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 30%;
 text-align: center;
}
#tabela1{
 border: 2px solid;
 width: 250px;
 position: relative;
 left: 20%;
 background: black;
 text-align: center;
 color: red;
}
#tabela2{
 border: 2px solid;
 width: 250px;
 position: relative;
 left: 20%;
 background: black;
 text-align: center;
 color: red;
}
#conteudo{
 border: 2px solid;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 left: 45%;
 top: 15%;
}
#showw{
 width: 599px;
 height: 399px;
}
#img1{
 width: 599px;
 height: 399px;
}

#btn1{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

#btn2{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

#btn3{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

#btn4{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

#btn5{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

#btn6{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #292929 0%,
  #ebebeb 52%,
  #dbdbdb 51%,
  #bd0a19);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#292929),
  color-stop(0.52, #ebebeb),
  color-stop(0.51, #dbdbdb),
  to(#bd0a19));
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 box-shadow:
 0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
 inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(000,000,000,1);
 text-shadow:
 0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.8),
 0px 1px 0px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Atividade Extra </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="js/meu-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="corpo">


 <div id="cpesquerdo">
  
  <br>
  <table id="tabela1">
   <tr>
    <td> Vídeos </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id="btn1"> Vídeo 1 </button>
  <button id="btn2"> Vídeo 2 </button>
  <button id="btn3"> Vídeo 3 </button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table  id="tabela2">
   <tr>
    <td> Imagens </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id="btn4"> Imagem 1 </button>
  <button id="btn5"> Imagem 2 </button>
  <button id="btn6"> Imagem 3 </button>

 </div>

 <div id="conteudo">
  <iframe id="showw">  </iframe>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

A imagem está aparecendo, porem não consigo alterar o tamanho dela, mesmo utilizando os comandos acima. Alguem sabe me ajudar? sou iniciante em javascript.
e tambem estou com problema quando coloco um link do youtube, aparece que A conexão com www.youtube.com foi recusada.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, já identifiquei, de cara, que você não definiu a unidade de medida em algumas propriedades. Exemplo: `img1.style.width = 30;` deveria ser algo como `img1.style.width = '30px';`.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a documentação do [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/), você pode manipular o CSS usando a função `.css()`.

No seu caso,

```
.css( "width", "30px" );
```

E no caso do YouTube, [YouTube API do IFrame](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) e [Incorporar vídeos e playlists](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=pt-BR), podem te ajudar.

Comment: vou tentar aqui

Comment: Não esqueça da unidade de medida conforme @LipESprY comentou

Answer (score 0):

você não precisa de CSS, o objeto já possui uma propriedade **"width"**

```
<script>
    var img1 = document.getElementById('showw')
    img1.src = "img/fusca1.jpg";
    img1.width = 30;
    img1.height = 30;
</script>
```

Não precisa de *img1.style.* use diretamente *img1.width*

Comment: tentei desta maneira tambem, mas acabou não funcionando tambem, mas obrigado mesmo assim!